# Stop Dropbox to autostart at boot/login on mac OS

Tags: macos

How to stop Dropbox to autostart at boot/login on mac OS ?

I have signed out of the dropbox app.

---

What i have tried

[image]

[image]

Comment: So… it's still in login items. What happens if you remove it?

Comment: Also look in Dropbox Preferences.  Uncheck the setting for starting when computer starts. That setting should be similar on Mac.

Comment: @John - OP already did that. That's the 2nd pic.